# Preencher formulário de página web usando aplicação em Java

Tags: java

Existe um site que preciso usar frequentemente.
Neste site preciso repetir uma sequência de passos.
Quero escrever um programa que automatize esse processo (tenho mais prática com Java, mas pode ser em qualquer linguagem).

Eu tentei o Selenium, mas ele abre o navegador e simula os comandos do usuário, quero algo que execute sem que o usuário veja.

A sequência de passos é a seguinte:

1. Login
2. Seleciona item no menu
3. Insere código do cliente
4. Seleciona item no menu
5. Clica em botão
6. Insere códigos dos produtos
7. Volta ao item 2

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: O que você já tentou? Adicione o que já tentou para que possam te ajudar.

Comment: Use o [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) então

Comment: Acho que o mais adequado seria o uso de uma API (webservice). Verifique se o site possui uma API.